# Live data on listview with baseadapter?

Tags: android, listview, live, baseadapter

I have a Listview with baseadapter. I am able to implement this segment - display the listview with data when i data is constant. When the data changes in a controlled manner like due to user input i am able to change this by calling notifydatasetchanged() on the adapter.

My actual requirement is that the info is drawn periodically from the internet at a constant
interval say  10 secs. How can i implement this situation. Also if the no. of items in the list
is very large then then how to control the memory usage by the adapter.

Comment: use lazy loading caching the response. So you don't need to get the data again. Use a `ViewHolder` pattern

Comment: [Performance Improvement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMRnGDR6Cu0)